# I get this message while run the code which I got it from codecanyon?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build

Launching lib\main.dart on SM N960F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':braintree_payment:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':braintree_payment:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.1-2.
> Required by:
> project :braintree_payment > com.braintreepayments.api:three-d-secure:3.7.2
> > Could not resolve org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.1-2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/org/jfrog/cardinalcommerce/gradle/cardinalmobilesdk/2.2.1-2/cardinalmobilesdk-2.2.1-2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/org/jfrog/cardinalcommerce/gradle/cardinalmobilesdk/2.2.1-2/cardinalmobilesdk-2.2.1-2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 403 Forbidden (error's last line). It means you don't have permission to access.

```
Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Comment: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':braintree_payment:compileDebugAidl'.  what about this message?

Comment: Because it got an error, ```Could not GET```. It's some permission problem with braintree_payment package. Now you need to find out why this is happening, if it's a package problem or you missed some installation step.

Comment: I'm just beginner , can you guess what i may be missed in installation cause this problem?

Comment: I have never worked with this package, but I can tell you what you can do to find the problem. You can begin reinstalling it or going back all the installation guide and check if you missed some step.